# Android print not printing Logo with thermal printer

Tags: android, android-studio, printing, thermal-printer

We have a thermal printer where we are trying to print a receipt for transactions.

We first generate a PDF, and then print the same using PrintService.

Here is the code for the same.

```
 @Override
    public void onLayout(PrintAttributes printAttributes, PrintAttributes printAttributes1, CancellationSignal cancellationSignal, LayoutResultCallback layoutResultCallback, Bundle bundle) {
        if (cancellationSignal.isCanceled()) {
            layoutResultCallback.onLayoutCancelled();
        } else {
            PrintDocumentInfo.Builder builder =
                    new PrintDocumentInfo.Builder(" file name");
            builder.setContentType(PrintDocumentInfo.CONTENT_TYPE_PHOTO)
                    .setPageCount(PrintDocumentInfo.PAGE_COUNT_UNKNOWN)
                    .build();
            layoutResultCallback.onLayoutFinished(builder.build(),
                    !printAttributes1.equals(printAttributes));
        }
    }
```

After initializiing the print service, we just read the pdf and send the same to the printer.

```
 @Override
    public void onWrite(PageRange[] pageRanges, ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor, CancellationSignal cancellationSignal, WriteResultCallback writeResultCallback) {
        InputStream in = null;
        OutputStream out = null;
        try {
            File file = new File(pathName);
            in = new FileInputStream(file);
            out = new FileOutputStream(parcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor());



            byte[] buf = new byte[16384];
            int size;

            while ((size = in.read(buf)) >= 0
                    && !cancellationSignal.isCanceled()) {
                out.write(buf, 0, size);
            }
        }
    }
```

But then we have a problem.
The While pdf print look like below, along with images -
[image]

The actual image does not contain logo and all other graphics.
This is how it looks

[image]
Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Please add the vendor and model number of the printer you are using. Alternatively, it can be a link to the corresponding control command specification. Without such information, it will be difficult to get accurate advice and answers.

Comment: We are using Intermec PR3 printer.

Comment: According to these articles, [How to print on Honeywell mobile printers using Java](https://honeywellaidc.force.com/supportppr/s/article/How-to-print-on-Honeywell-mobile-printers-using-Java), [PR2 and PR3: ESC-P / CSim / XSim Developer's Guide](https://support.honeywellaidc.com/s/article/PR2-and-PR3-ESC-P-CSim-XSim-Developer-s-Guide), [Honeywell Android Printing SDKs](https://support.honeywellaidc.com/s/article/Honeywell-Android-Printing-SDKs) the printer seems to support three different control command schemes. Please get the specifications and SDK and check them out.

Comment: Alternatively, these articles may be better. [How to print from Android to the Honeywell families of printers](https://honeywellaidc.force.com/supportppr/s/article/How-to-print-from-Android-to-the-Honeywell-families-of-printers), [Is there a Honeywell App for Mobile Printers to send a test print from Android or iOs?](https://support.honeywellaidc.com/s/article/RL-RP-Is-there-a-Honeywell-App-to-send-a-test-print-from-Android), [Print Service by Honeywell showing Demo Mode](https://support.honeywellaidc.com/s/article/Print-Service-by-Honeywell-showing-Demo-Mode)